# Infinite prefab spawn bug

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript

I have a simple spawn script for my 2D game that i wrote, that i want to spawn an object after a specific period of time. I managed to get this to work but the one problem is that the object keeps spawning. I just want the object to spawn once not an infinite amount.

```js
var myTimer : float = 5.0;
var thePrefab : GameObject;

function Update () {
    if(myTimer > 0){
        myTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if(myTimer <= 0){
        var instance : GameObject = Instantiate(thePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity3D: Spawning an object based on current position - putting onto canvas in same position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923953/unity3d-spawning-an-object-based-on-current-position-putting-onto-canvas-in-s)

Comment: hi @usernameisnotprogrammedyet if possible try to *search first*, you could have found a zillion QA on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By shifting around your if statements, you can restrict your object to only spawning once:

```js
var myTimer : float = 5.0;
var thePrefab : GameObject;

function Update () {
    if(myTimer > 0){
        myTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

        if(myTimer <= 0){
            var instance : GameObject = Instantiate(thePrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the object will only spawn if `myTimer > 0` prior to the decrement, and `myTimer <= 0` following the decrement - which only happens once.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help you out.

Comment: While it is totally admirable to help new Unity hobbyists, consider there is a HUGE problem with clutter in the Unity3D tag here.  *Indeed it is becoming very difficult to get questions seen or answered*.  Consider it's often best to just close the question, perhaps leaving a helpful comment if necessary

Comment: @JoeBlow Ah, gotcha. Although not certain the suggested duplicate is applicable in this case - the error was in the OP's code logic, and not on being able to set a parent for their game object.

Comment: hi @serlite.  One thing is, don't forget, use ***any close reason you like***. Nobody really looks at or cares about close reasons much. This could also be closed as "caused by a simple typographical error" "too vague" and more.

Comment: @JoeBlow Oh, huh...I try to use my close votes wherever I can (I agree that the Unity3D tag is a bit of a cesspool of low-quality/effort questions), but I suspect our close-voting heuristics differ somewhat, haha.

Comment: Indeed, try to close all trivial questions. Consider my comment here for instance ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429034/unity-3d-double-sided-shader-with-alpha-and-depth-masking ... a real shame.  This site could easily become like answers.unity3d ..... totally useless and non-functioning.